# Are push notification received on my device even if the app is not running (not even in background) ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Are push notification received on my device even if the app is not running (not even in background) ?

A customer told me he received a notification even if the app was close (in the multi-tasking bar was also not there).

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Push notifications will be received if your app is not running.

From [the apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html):

> If a notification for an application arrives when that application is not running, the device alerts the user that the application has data waiting for it.

Comment: Can I disable them instead !?

Comment: The entire point of push notifications is to be able to do stuff when your app isn't running. Why use them if you don't want that capability?

Comment: I'm using them to send messages when the app is in background. Let's say "I receive a message from a friend." But if the user quits the app then I don't want him to receive such messages. (Or receiving them when he opens the app again).

Comment: As far as I know you'd have to tell your server not to send them.

Comment: How can the server know if the app is close ?

Comment: You'd have to ping it from the application delegate. Might be hard to differentiate between backgrounded and dead though - i think iOS can kill backgrounded apps without telling you

Comment: So when the app is closed, I should send such information to the server, and store it together with the device identifier ?